# The Build Summary Cannot Display Test Coverage

Tags: tfs, code-coverage, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

The problem happen after our on-demand TFS server upgrade to 2015 update 3. Before we are using Update 1, everything works fine. The problem is: in the build summary the unit test coverage section is empty and complain "No build code coverage data available. "

[image]

But actually, we enable the coverage inside the build task and the .coverage file already published from the build agent onto server during the task running. From the test run details, we can see in the attachment:

[image]

And in the task configure, we already check:

[image]

Some Update:
1. The VS version is already Enterprise version as the .coverage file is generated successfully.
2. Remove the test run setting file does not help.

Comment: Can it display if you create a simple unit test and enable the code coverage?

Comment: Which edition of VS do you install on your build agent server? Only Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise has Code Coverage feature.

Comment: I try to remove the run setting file, but still no coverage on summary page.

Comment: Can you share the logs for VSTest step?